# Повышается ли производительность труда веб-программиста при использовании редактора Emacs или Vim?

Tags: vim, emacs

Собственно, сабж. Стоит ли переходить на них в целях повышения скорости и удобства работы с кодом?

Comment: Это зависит как минимум от того, в чем вы там кодите сейчас

Comment: При условии, что он хорошо знает свой инструмент. Но если человек начинает использовать vim/emacs, то с большой вероятностью он начинает использовать линукс и его командную строку. А вот это уже сильно может повысить производительность. Например, для обновления сайта может быть написан один скрипт, который будет запускаться прямо с vim'а.

Comment: Если не гостайна, в чём работаете сейчас?  
Если в блокноте, то конечно переходите.

Comment: В Sublime Text 2, реже в Notepad++ и Scite

Comment: Sublime Text 2 при правильном использовании очень неплох.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На мой взгляд, у этих редакторов пологая кривая вхождения. То есть вы будете долго их изучать и привыкать к ним, но когда (и если!) привыкнете, ваша производительность существенно возрастёт. Так что это долгосрочная инвестиция времени.

Не забывайте, однако, что многие IDE обеспечивают тоже неплохие возможности для редактирования, особенно текста программ. Например, майкрософтовский Intellisense очень неплох для C# (для C++ субъективно хуже).

Пробуйте, сравнивайте, выбирайте.

Answer (score 4):

Пользуюсь вимом длительное время. На механическое заучивание основных команд ушел примерно месяц, в этот период времени не сильно упала производительность - максимум на 10-15%.

Как навык выработается, так скорость работы с текстом повысится примерно в два раза, за счёт исключения мыши и режимного подхода при редактировании кода.

Единственное необходимое требование: вы **должны** уметь печатать **вслепую**.

Настроенный лично под вас редактор (удобные горячие клавиши, сниппеты, поиск, переход по файлам и другое) повысит производительность более, чем любая IDE.

Но нужно понимать, вим - редактор в большей степени. 
Если нужна отладка - то лучше в IDE (зависит от языка).

Плюс скорость работы вима как приложения выше, чем у IDE.

Comment: А как может повыситься скорость работы с текстом аж в два раза. Мне кажется наоборот. Одно только нажатие на Esc в 2 раза сокращает ;)

Comment: Самое главное - редактор настраивается под пользователя. Если вам не удобно нажимать клавишу "Esc", то можно её переназначить по усмотрению. Я для себя лично определил выход из режима редактирования по двойному нажатию клавиш "jj". 
Но, справедливости ради, стоит заметить, что "магия" этого редактора проявляется при использовании большей части его стандартных возможностей по управлению текстом.